# Get camera FCurve

Tags: python

```py
object.animation_data.action.fcurves
```

Always works on any object, but if try it on a camera

> Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\korb\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\plugin_*init*_.py", line 155, in execute
> cf = camera.animation_data.action.fcurves
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'action'

Comment: Going to need to see the script, but the `NoneType` suggests that `camera` isn't pointing to an actual object, or the object doesn't have animation data, because this works: `>>> camera = C.scene.camera
>>> camera.animation_data.action.fcurves
bpy.data.actions['CameraAction'].fcurves`

Comment: Looking at the specifics of your error message, it looks like your camera doesn't have animation data.  Because the 'NoneType' message refers to 'action', and not 'animation_data', by the way

Comment: It does have animation data (focal lenght)

Comment: Python is telling you that it doesn't.  Can you go to the Python cancel and type `if camera.animation_data is None: print('oops')`

Comment: i got a oops on the terminal

Comment: So you have an object identified by `camera` that in fact has no animation_data set.  Are you setting `camera` to the correct object?

Comment: i animated the camera rotation and it worked, so the problem is that blender does not recognizes the focal lenght keys as animation data... no idea what to do now

Comment: You need to select the camera differently.  If I animate the focal length of the scene camera, it doesn't show up in `bpy.context.scene.camera` or `bpy.data.objects["Camera"]` but in `bpy.data.cameras["Camera"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug your problem, look closely at this part of the error message:

> in execute cf = camera.animation_data.action.fcurves AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'action'

`NoneType` is telling you that one of the attributes of `camera.animation_data.action.fcurves` has no value and so it can't have an attribute.

`action` is telling you where Python had to stop parsing the variable.  The attribute before `action` is `animation_data`.  This tells you that `camera` has an empty `animation_data` attribute.

You confirmed this by running the suggested test:

```
if camera.animation_data is None: print('oops')
```

on the Python console.  It printed "oops" verifying that the value of `camera.animation_data` was empty.

It turned out that the reason for this is because you had set `camera` incorrectly, perhaps by setting it to `bpy.context.scene.camera` or `bpy.data.objects["Camera"]`.  That's because when you animated the *focal length*, (the variable is `lens`, by the way) The animation data was actually attached to `bpy.data.cameras["Camera"]`.

So that means that the reference you need is `bpy.data.cameras["Camera"].animation_data.action.fcurves`.

This of course, is only true if there is only one camera and you haven't changed its name to something other than "Camera".  In other cases, you'd have to find a different way to select the correct camera from `bpy.data.cameras`.